# Method to order list with dependancies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, list, methods

Conditions: Have to use web based solution (HTML/CSS), Have to use Ruby on Rails, no use of database.

Imagine we have a list of jobs, each represented by a character. Because certain jobs must be done before others, a job may have a dependency on another job. For example, a may depend on b, meaning the final sequence of jobs should place b before a. If a has no dependency, the position of a in the final sequence does not matter. These jobs would be input with a simple text box (also how does one store multiple variables)

Given the following job structure:

- a =>
- b =>
- c =>

The result should be a sequence containing all three jobs abc in no significant order.

Given the following job structure:

- a =>
- b => c
- c => f
- d => a
- e => b
- f =>

The result should be a sequence that positions f before c, c before b, b before e and a before d containing all six jobs abcdef.

Given the following job structure:

- a =>
- b => c
- c => f
- d => a
- e =>
- f => b

The result should be an error stating that jobs can’t have circular dependencies.

Comment: this isn't a place to do your homework for you.

Comment: Im sorry but this isn't homework, im working on a small project and im very new to rails so this is a starting point for me.

Comment: See "Completed Solutions" section: http://invalidcast.tumblr.com/

Comment: I suppose SO also isn't a place to do your job for you? I don't see a meaningful distinction between school work and job work. I think it's just fine to ask for homework help on SO.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
module JobDependenciesResolver    

  def self.organize(dependencies)
    unresolved_dependencies = dependencies.dup
    sorted_jobs = []

    until unresolved_dependencies.empty? do
      doable_jobs = get_doable_jobs unresolved_dependencies, sorted_jobs
      raise Exception.new("Not able to resolve dependencies") if doable_jobs.empty?
      sorted_jobs += doable_jobs
      unresolved_dependencies.delete_if {|key,value| sorted_jobs.include? key}
    end

    sorted_jobs
  end

  private

  def self.get_doable_jobs(dependencies, job_array)
    dependencies.select {|job, dependency| ([*dependency]-job_array).empty? }.keys        
  end
end
```